# Comparação de texto

Tags: php

Estou com uma dúvida ao comparar variáveis.

Recebo um valor variável em uma `string` e preciso compara-lo com outra `string`.

Por exemplo:

```
$var1 = "M. D. AQUI";
$var2 = "MD AQUI"; // COM PONTUAÇÃO OU SEM PONTUAÇÃO. COM ESPAÇOS OU SEM ESPAÇOS.
```

Bom, eu tentei fazer um *replace* na variável, trocando os pontos por nada mas, o espaço continua. Não posso tirar o espaço porque o texto ficará todo junto.

```
$result = str_replace(". ", "", $var1); // resultado: MDAQUI  / Com isso não consigo fazer a comparação de semelhanças.
```

Alguém poderia ajudar com o código ou indicar uma ferramenta de estudo?

Comment: No `str_replace(". ", "", $var1);` retire o espaço e deixe só o ponto, assim: `str_replace(".", "", $var1);`.

Comment: Eu já fiz desse modo mas, ainda há um problema.
Por exemplo: Se eu tirar os pontos de M. D. AQUI o resultado será M D AQUI se comparar com MD AQUI o resultado é false;

Comment: *Faca* é diferente de *Faça*, mas se eu tirar o cedilha, ficam iguais. Qual a lógica real de alterar a palavra? Que tipo de comparação você precisa fazer? Você considera os acentos?

Answer (score 1):

O que tens de fazer é retirar todos os espaços ou pontos das **DUAS** strings:

```
$var1 = str_replace(".", "", $var1);
$var1 = str_replace(" ", "", $var1);
$var2 = str_replace(".", "", $var2);
$var2 = str_replace(" ", "", $var2);

$var1==$var2  (true)
```

Se quiseres fazer uma comparação de semelhanças como disseste no código podes usar a função [`similar_text`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.similar-text.php):

```
$var1 = strtoupper("M. D. AQUI");
$var2 = strtoupper("MD AQUI");

similar_text($var1, $var2, $percentagemDeSemelhanca);
echo $percentagemDeSemelhanca;

//resultado => 82.3529411765
```

Assim saberás a percentagem de semelhança das duas strings. Usei ali o [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtoupper.php) para aumentar a probabilidade de semelhança entre strings no caso de elas não estarem em maiúsculas.

[Exemplo PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5gqh-wdf8)

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo, ajudou bastante.

Vou utilizar a função similar_text.

Obrigado.

Comment: Se esta ou outra resposta respondeu a sua pergunta não se esqueça de aceitar a resposta. Veja [Como e porque aceitar respostas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @JorgeB., `strtoupper` teria problema com acentos, sugiro `MB*` para evitar problema entre a comparação.

Answer (score 0):

Uma abordagem ligeiramente diferente, que permite não **depender** de [similar_text()](http://www.php.net/similar_text), facultando seu uso, por remover os pontos e espaços regular e condicionalmente.

Pra essa abordagem, o ideal seria usar [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) mas com dois [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) consecutivos a ER fica mais limpa:

```
$var1 = "M. D. AQUI";
$var2 = "MD AQUI";

$var1 = preg_replace( '/(\w)\.\s+(?!\w{2,})/', '$1', $var1 ); // MD. AQUI

$var1 = preg_replace( '/(\w)\.\s+(?=\w{2,})/', '$1 ', $var1 ); // MD AQUI

if( $var1 != $var2 ) {

    similar_text( $var1, $var2, $percentual );

    if( $percentual > 70 ) {

        // Strings similares, faz alguma coisa
    }

} else {

    // Strings iguais
}
```

A primeira substituição remove os pontos e os espaços das letras individuais caso elas não sejam seguidas por uma palavra com mais de uma letra.

A segunda faz a mesma coisa, mas ao contrário. Se a letra e o ponto forem seguidos por uma palavra maior, remove o ponto, mas adiciona um espaço extra.

Assim não fica "tudo grudado".

Essa abordagem tem como vantagens:

- Manipular apenas uma das strings, o que é útil caso a segunda venha de uma origem fixa a qual você não possa ou não deva alterar
- Não obriga o uso de [similar text()](http://www.php.net/similar_text) pois, pelo menos no cenário exposto, as strings passam a ser iguais. Caso não sejam e você queira se apoiar em [similar_text()](http://www.php.net/similar_text) como *fallback*, ela diminui a probabilidade de o percentual retornar um falso-positivo com um *score* muito baixo.